# Regex OR pattern not retrieving match

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following `Regex Pattern`

```
/string\s+(?|(x)|(ix|iv|v?i{0,3})|([a-j]))/i
```

When I use this with the input

```
String a
```

I don't get a match for `a`

If I remove the middle `or` condition or move this condition to earlier in the pattern, it picks it up.

http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/26

Would someone know what is going on here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the inbetween `v?i{0,3}` regex. If you change your regex like,

```
/string\s+(?|(x)|(ix|iv|v?i{1,3})|([a-j]))/i
```

it would work. NOrmally regex engine would take the pattern from left to right. So after `string\s+`, it takes `(x)`, but there isn't a character `x`, so this would fail. Next it goes to `(ix|iv|v?i{0,3})` and takes the first `ix`. But there isn't `ix` or `iv` so these also fail. Next it takes this `v?i{0,3})` pattern. An optional `v` and an `i` 0 upto three times. So an inbetween empty string would be matched. So finally we got a match and the regex engine won't go for the next OR condition.

Comment: This doesn't match `v`, unlike the original.

Comment: @choroba i  explained the reason, if op wants to match `string v` then he could use `string\s+(?|(x)|(ix|iv|v?(?:i{1,3})?)|([a-j]))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following part:

```
v?i{0,3}
```

Notice that if `v` is missing and there's no `i`, it still matches. You can fix the problem by adding `$` to the end of the regex. Or, optimize the Roman numerals in a different way:

```
/string\s+(?|(i?[xv]|v?i{1,3})|([a-j]))/i
```